# SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, request

SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'pay_totals' at row 1

```
public function order(Request $req){
        $order = new Order;
        $order->pay_number = $req->checkout_number;
        $order->pay_totals = $req->checkout_total;
        $order->save();
        return redirect(route('pay'))->with('message','Sending infomation successfully');
    }
```

blade:

```
<input type="text" name="checkout_total" value="{{Cart::subTotal('0') }} ">
```

Helppp

Comment: The root cause of this error lies with MySQL, and as we can't see anything about your database table I don't think this question is answerable.  Most likely, you are trying to store some data which is too wide to fit in the target column, and MySQL is warning you about this.

Comment: should've just used TEXT : https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/understanding-strorage-sizes-for-mysql-text-data-types/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem is that column `pay_totals` can't store whatever you are getting from the input because is too big.

**Possibles solutions**

**SQL:** `ALTER TABLE [orders] ALTER COLUMN [pay_totals] VARCHAR(MAX)`

**MYSQL:** `ALTER TABLE [orders] MODIFY COLUMN [pay_totals] VARCHAR(60000)`

Answer (score 19):

Same error can be occurred due **data type mismatching**. As an example,if you are assigning an string to float, you will get this error. so be sure to check whether the data are in correct type. I got this error on **symfony**.

Answer (score 13):

In some cases this message appears where the field type is `ENUM` and the sent data didn't define in `ENUM` range .
So that's need to check the `ENUM` values in your table and update them before submiting.

Answer (score 5):

Some times this error occurred due to inserting data into extra columns like `('created_at','updated_At')` in pivot table. Below solution works for me.

**Error Code**

```
$users=User::create($input['data']);
foreach ($input['products'] as $product) {
    if (array_key_exists('special_price', $product)) {
        $userProducts[$product['id']] = ['special_price' => $product['special_price']];
    } else {
        $userProducts[$product['id']] = ['special_price' => ''];
    }
    $userProducts['created_at'] = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
    $userProducts['updated_at'] = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
}

//individual product with special price of each product
/*
Output before code correction

array (1 =>
array(
    'special_price' => '',
),
'created_at' => '2019-04-07 14:28:27',
'updated_at' => '2019-04-07 14:28:27',))
*/
$users->products()->sync($userProducts);
```

**Code Correction**

```
$users=User::create($input['data']);
foreach ($input['products'] as $product) {
    if (array_key_exists('special_price', $product)) {
        $userProducts[$product['id']] = ['special_price' => $product['special_price']];
    } else {
        $userProducts[$product['id']] = ['special_price' => ''];
    }
    // below lines are after code correction
    $userProducts[$product['id']]['created_at'] = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
    $userProducts[$product['id']]['updated_at'] = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
}

//individual product with special price of each product
/*
Output after code correction

array (1 =>
array(
    'special_price' => '',
    'created_at' => '2019-04-07 14:28:27',
    'updated_at' => '2019-04-07 14:28:27',
),)
*/
$users->products()->sync($userProducts);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is maybe because you have declared different datatype (e.g. ENUM) and you are sending different datatype in frontend(e.g. string). so at that time you might get this error.